# Background image is not fixing to window using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, background-image

I am using bootstrap 3 i added background image in body its not taking full image, image is cropping below.please help me anyone. i am trying very long back. how to fix full background image in all devices without scroll.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;       
min-height:768px;
height:auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-image: url("../images/login/****.jpg");
```

Comment: If you want to full size image so call "background-size:cover" or you want to fixed "background-attachment:fixed"

Comment: i called "background-size:cover" but background image is disappeared

Comment: can you share your html or url

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>test</title>
 
<style>

body
{  
    
   background-repeat: no-repeat;       
    min-height:768px;
    height:1100px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image: url("login_background_image.jpg"); 
}
</style>     
</head>
<body>           
</body>
</html>

Comment: http://test.newui.myddf.info/   please check background image  @Awadheshverma

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is in the `body` element, if you want a full screen background-image, you can try this

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```